# Push notification to mobile when Google form is submitted

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-forms, android-sdk-2.3

In my application. There is a functionaity where users fill Google forms and submit the response. The response will sit in the Google spreadsheet upon form submission. After generating JSONObject using script(Google Apps Script API). i am able to populate data to ListView. My Question is how can i able to achieve like the creator (admin) or admins of the form should get push notification to mobile when a new response is submitted through form. (without using third party app.)

Comment: You can "install" an "On Form Submit" trigger in a script bound to the Form.  That will run code in Apps Script every time that the Form is submitted.  That would be the starting point.  There is no native service in Apps Script to send a push notification.  You can make an HTTPS GET or POST request from Apps Script using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Comment: I'm not sure it the following documentation is what you need, but take a look:  [Link to Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push)

Comment: [Link to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use IFTTT with the [Google Forms add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/email_notifications_for_google_forms/984866591130) to send [push notifications](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-forms-mobile-notifications/29203/) to your mobile when a new form is submitted.

[image: Google Forms Mobile Notifications]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already implemented this solution following you tutorial in YT. Is there any way that i could implement push notification within android app without using third-party app.

Comment: To everyone using this solution: BEWARE that this envolves sharing your data with an unverified app. Mind when using sensitive or personal data.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com).

1. Inside IFTTT create a new Applet
2. For the "THIS" part search for "Google Spreadsheet"
3. You'll find a recipe triggered when "a row is added to a spreadsheet". Connect it and follow instructions.
4. For the "THAT" part search for "Notifications" and follow instructions.
5. Download the IFTTT app on your phone.

Now every time the form is submitted a new row on your spreadsheet is going to trigger a notification on your mobile phone.